# How can I use {{#each}} to show many nested objects in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, spacebars

Using the below MongoDB subdocument how can I use the `{{#each}}` block helper (or really any method) to iterate over the objects inside of `recurring`?

```
"recurring": {
    "T12345" : {
        "amount" : 102,
        "created_at" : "2014-09-29T17:43:18.414627+00:00",
        "status": "pending",
        "guid" : "T12345"
    },
    "T12346" : {
        "amount" : 102,
        "created_at" : "2014-09-30T17:45:02.768939+00:00",
        "status": "succeeded",
        "guid" : "T12346",

    }
}
```

JS file

```
Template.subscription.helpers({
subscription: function () {
    return this.recurring.transactions; //The subscription filters out the records marked viewable: false
},
    fname: function() {
        return this.customer.fname;
    },
    lname: function() {
        return this.customer.lname;
    },
    amount: function() {
        return this.debit.amount / 100;
    },
    trans_guid: function(key) {
        return this.recurring.transactions.key; //not sure how I can get the guid since the object that holds this property is named using the same guid
    }
});
```

HTML File

```
<table class="table bootstrap-datatable datatable small-font">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Fund</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
    {{#each subscription}}
        <tr>
            <td><span class="label label-success">{{status}}</span></td>
            <td>{{trans_date}}</td>
            <td>{{fund}}</td>
            <td>{{amount}}</td>
            <td><b>{{trans_guid}}</b></td>
        </tr>                       
    {{/each}}                                                                               
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a link to a larger part of my MongoDB document
https://gist.github.com/c316/20d82003e61aefd3623e

What I'm trying to do is show all the transactions for this one subscription. There may only be one or there many be hundreds. Right now the Meteor is subscribing to the whole document so how do I tell meteor where to look to list each of the transactions?

EDIT ANSWER

HTML file

```
{{#each addKeys subscription}}
    {{#with values}}
        <tr id="{{trans_guid}}" class="trans-table-row">
            <td><span class="label label-success">{{status}}</span></td> <!-- label-warning label-info label-danger label-success  -->
            <td>{{trans_date}}</td>
            <td>{{fund ../..}}</td>
            <td>{{amount}}</td>
            <td><b>{{trans_guid}}</b></td>
        </tr>
    {{/with}}                       
{{/each}}
```

JS file

```
Template.subscription.helpers({
    values: function() {
        return this;
    },
    status: function() {
        return this.value.status;
    },
    fund: function(parentContext) {
        return parentContext.debit.donateTo;//getDonateTo();
    },
    trans_date: function() {
        return moment(this.value.updated_at).format("MM-DD-YYYY hh:mma");
    },
    amount: function() {
        return "$" + (Math.floor(this.value.amount) / 100).toFixed(2);
    },
    trans_guid: function() {
        return this.value.guid;
    }
});
Template.registerHelper('addKeys', function (all) {
    return _.map(all, function(i, k) {
        return {key: k, value: i};
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS:

```js
Template.registerHelper('addKeys', function (all) {
    return _.map(all, function(i, k) {
        return {key: k, value: i};
    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<tbody>
    {{#each addKeys subscription}}
      {{#with value}}
        <tr>
            <td><span class="label label-success">{{status}}</span></td>
            <td>{{trans_date}}</td>
            <td>{{fund}}</td>
            <td>{{amount}}</td>
            <td><b>{{trans_guid}}</b></td>
        </tr>
      {{/with}}                 
    {{/each}}                                                                               
</tbody>
```

Comment: I updated my question to show more of my code. Can you help me understand how I can use your answer with my question update?

Comment: your html and database records don't match up, so I'm not sure where you want to get the data from, e.g., for `fund`, but I think the update I just made to my answer is what you were looking for.

Comment: I added a gist of the Mongodb document. I know I don't understand exactly what is going on here or I think I'd be able to figure out how to use your answer in my particular case. I'm just not finding anything online that clarifies. I used your changes in my code, but I still don't have it working. Thanks for updating your answer. Given the document do you know what I need to do in my JS file to get the right data?

Comment: i still don't understand your question. Maybe it would help if you could say which fields of the mongodb document you'd like to use, and hence what output you'd like to see for this document.

Comment: I'd like to see a list of transactions (a table really). So that is everything inside transactions: {}

I'm picturing a table with one row for each transaction. The data inside the row would be amount, created_at and some others too.

Comment: Christian, thanks for your help on this. I do appreciate it. I'm not sure what other information to provide here to be more clear about what I'm trying to accomplish. Please let me know if I still need to add more information. Thanks again.